# Angular Link not leading to component

Tags: angular, web, apache2

I am currently using the Angular Router for my internal links:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'imprint', component: ImprintComponent } ....
   ];
```

As webserver I use Apache2 on a Debian Server.

My problem is when I access for example `mydomain.com/imprint` it does not lead to the internal link. I get an 404 error page. How do I fix that?

Comment: what is happening while mydomain.com in link?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean when you try to open page with domain only what is happening ?

Answer (score 2):

You get a 404 because the web server is looking for a folder called "imprint". Your best option is to use the HashLocationStrategy. This page explains it quite nicely:

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy